# Find $\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} e^{-a(\sin(x)+\cos(x))} \, dx$ and/or $\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} e^{-a(\sin(x)+\cos(x))} \sin(\cos(x)) \, dx$

Tags: calculus, exponential-function, improper-integrals, indefinite-integrals

While trying to solve a certain integral I was left with these rather silly integral.

$$\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} e^{-a(\sin(x)+\cos(x))} \, dx$$
$$\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} e^{-a(\sin(x)+\cos(x))} \sin(\cos(x)) \, dx$$

Any headway on these problems would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: They seem [close to Bessel](http://people.math.sfu.ca/~cbm/aands/page_376.htm). Maybe, you can try that path.